# Fill the empty cells with their neighbours if they are not empty based on another column Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Good afternoon,

What is the simplest way to replace empty values to another value in one column if the text in the another column is equal?

For example, we have the dataframe:

| Name | Life | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 789 | 45 |
| Joe | 563 | 13 |
| Nick |  | 24 |
| Nick | 45 | 155 |
| Alice | 188 | 34 |
| Alice |  | 43 |
| Kate |  | 43543 |
| Kate |  | 232 |

And the result should be:

| Name | Life | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 789 | 45 |
| Joe | 563 | 13 |
| Nick | 45 | 24 |
| Nick | 45 | 155 |
| Alice | 188 | 34 |
| Alice | 188 | 43 |
| Kate |  | 43543 |
| Kate |  | 232 |

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Depending on your data, maybe `df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda g: g.ffill().bfill())` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Joe', 'Joe', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Kate', 'Kate'],
    'Life': [789.0, np.nan, np.nan, 45.0, 188.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Score': [45, 13, 24, 155, 34, 43, 43543, 232]
})
print(df)

# output:
#     Name   Life  Score
# 0    Joe  789.0     45
# 1    Joe    NaN     13
# 2   Nick    NaN     24
# 3   Nick   45.0    155
# 4  Alice  188.0     34
# 5  Alice    NaN     43
# 6   Kate    NaN  43543
# 7   Kate    NaN    232


df['Life'] = df.groupby('Name')['Life'].transform('first')
print(df)

# output:
#     Name   Life  Score
# 0    Joe  789.0     45
# 1    Joe  789.0     13
# 2   Nick   45.0     24
# 3   Nick   45.0    155
# 4  Alice  188.0     34
# 5  Alice  188.0     43
# 6   Kate    NaN  43543
# 7   Kate    NaN    232
```

Comment: it doesn't work if some Names have all values. For example, if both of Joe have values in "Life" (789 and 589), the code will replace the correct value to 789 and it will be (789 and 789) :(